# How do I prepend a prefix to Ant's srcfile marker within the apply task?

Tags: command-line, ant, mstest

Given the following ant task:

```
    <apply executable="${mstest}" addsourcefile="false">
        <arg value="/resultsfile:TestResults.trx" />
        <arg value="/testsettings:ReleaseCodeCoverage.testsettings" />
        <arg value="/detail:errormessage" />
        <srcfile />
        <fileset dir="bin/${buildType}">
            <patternset>
                <include name="*Tests.dll" />
            </patternset>
        </fileset>
    </apply>
```

**How can I apply the prefix `/TestContainer:` to the contents of `<srcfile />`?**

MSTest delimits switch names with a semicolon, not a space, so I can't just append it as `<arg value="/TestContainer">`. I've also tried `<srcfile prefix="/TestContainer:" />` as suggested [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50553#c4), but this is not supported in my version (1.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a cheat, but you might be able to adapt it to your case.  The [`apply` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) has a nested element `targetfile` that can be used in the same way as `srcfile` - placed between the command arguments where needed.  The value of targetfile is derived from srcfile using a mapper element.  So you can attach prefixes.  Something like this perhaps:

```
<apply executable="${mstest}" addsourcefile="false" relative="true">
    <arg value="/resultsfile:TestResults.trx" />
    <arg value="/testsettings:ReleaseCodeCoverage.testsettings" />
    <arg value="/detail:errormessage" />
    <targetfile/>
    <fileset dir="bin/${buildType}">
        <patternset>
            <include name="*Tests.dll" />
        </patternset>
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)" to="/TestContainer:bin/${buildType}/\1" />
</apply>
```

Note the use of the `relative` attribute, otherwise the path gets prefixed in front of the target 'filename'.

Comment: I had to change \1 to \0 because it was converting /TestContainer to d:\TestContainer. Thank you! I knew there had to be a way!